# No module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following programs installed

1. python 2.7 installed
2. Numpy-1.6.2-python2.7
3. Matplotlib-1.1.1-py2.7

I believe numpy has been installed properly because when I type import numpy in python interpreter, it doesn't give me an error. I can also check the version of the numpy installed.

I am getting the following error in my code on this line

```
import numpy as np
```

"Exceptions.ImportError:No module named numpy"

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: how are you running your code vs. opening the python interpreter? Just typing `python` from the command line?

Comment: do you have **only** python 27 installed?

Comment: Are you working in a virtualenv, or did you install numpy in your system site-packages?

Comment: @COpython I am running my code in PyScript. I used command line to check if numpy was correctly installed by typing "import numpy"

Comment: @DougT. I have python 2.7.3 installed

Comment: @BalthazarRouberol I an not working under virtual enviroment.

Comment: Sounds like you have another version of Python installed that PyScript is seeing. Easiest solution is to not use PyScript, but you may be able to fix it by re-installing/re-configuring PyScript to make sure that it points to the same location/version of your Python27

Comment: Ok. i will try reinstalling pyscript and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @COpython It seems to have worked! Thanks~~

Comment: @COpython:  Why don't you write that up as answer.  I'll be happy to supply an upvote.

Comment: @user1040943 wrote it up as an answer, do you mind choosing it as answer? (click the little green checkmark)

Answer (score 28):

in terminal:

sudo apt-get install python-numpy

Comment: This fixed for me also. What's the deal with this though? I installed via `pip`—why is that not enough? EDIT: Looks like probably two different pythons installed, and linked python/pip versions mixed.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have another version of Python installed that PyScript is seeing. Easiest solution is to not use PyScript, but you may be able to fix it by re-installing/re-configuring PyScript to make sure that it points to the same location/version of your Python27

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you have multiple versions of python installed, type:

```
which python
```

in your terminal, see what's the current one.

Answer (score 1):

I've same issue on Mac.
But I solve it. I have two versions of pip.Look....

```
MacBook-Pro:WhiteBoxSMS4-master qinyao$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip
MacBook-Pro:WhiteBoxSMS4-master qinyao$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
```

so,you need check you pip version.

Answer (score 0):

I've same issue on Mac OS X.

The numpy has been installed at '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override',
so `import numpy` works normaly.

But will fail while virtualenv actived, and with non-system preinstalled python(e.g. homebrew, or macport).

> ```
> $ which python
> /usr/local/bin/python
> ```

Fixed by install it again in virtualenv(which created with --no-site-packages option, or without --system-site-packages).

Answer (score 0):

Pylab is part of matplotlib; so you can simply install matplotlib and you will automatically get pylab, too.