# I've imported all the requirements for matplotlib, but I am still running into errors

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am running into issues with my program, and have followed many numerous things on here to help me. I've imported matplotlib, six,dateutil, nympy, but I still am running into errors. I have a feeling I have installed something improperly, but I am not sure. The error at the moment is "No module named 'numpy'" Which there is at least I believe there is. I have pasted the code and what it is supposed to be doing down below.

```
import math
import six
import matplotlib
import dateutil
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



Numbers = 'Yes'
Start = 'Yes'
i = 0
x = 0
Summands = 0
Mean = 0
Square_Summands = 0
Square_Root = 0
Number_List = []

Numbers = 'Yes'
while(Numbers == 'Yes'):

    Number_List.append(float(input('Please Enter A Number: ')))

    Summands = sum(Number_List)
    Mean = Summands/len(Number_List)
    Low = min(Number_List)
    High = max(Number_List)
    Square_Root = Number_List[x] * Number_List[x]
    Square_Summands = Square_Summands + Square_Root
    Standard_Deviation = math.sqrt(Square_Summands/len(Number_List))

    x+=1

    plt.plot(Standard_Deviation)
    plt.show()

    print('The Mean of the Numbers is: ', Mean)

    print('The High of the Numbers is: ', High)

    print('The Low of the Numbers is: ', Low)

    print('The Sum of the numbers is: ', Summands)

    print('The Standard Deviation of the numbers is: ', Standard_Deviation)


    Numbers = input('Do you want to add more numbers?, Yes or No: ')

while(i < len(Number_List)):
    print('#',i, ' = ', Number_List[i], end=' ')
    i = i +1

    Start = input('\n Do you want to Start Over, Yes or No?: ')
```

1. Capture an unlimited amount of numbers
2. Do and display calculations
3. Sum the numbers
4. find average
5. find the min and max
6. calculate standard deviation
7. display the numbers horizontally across a line labeling each number as #0: through #?:
8. Label each mathematical calulation and display its result on a line by line basis
9. plot the calculated standard deviations on a line segment and connect the dots with a curve.

> The issue that I had earlier seems to have been that I was trying to run different versions of numpy, six, matplot I was either running a 32/64 bit version without realizing it.I was directed to [Christoph Gohlke's repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) where I was able to find the proper versions for each one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No module named numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237522/no-module-named-numpy)

Comment: I've looked at that and don't understand it. I've been half tempted to reinstall python, and the other libs again. Think that might clear somethings up If I messed up somewhere?

Comment: "importing" and "installing" aren't the same thing. There are no requirements to importing matplotlib; you can `import matplotlib` without ever doing an `import numpy` (although you might have a hard time writing anything useful that way…). But there are requirements to _installing_ matplotlib, and if you manually install a pre-built binary of it without having NumPy installed, any code that uses it will fail (with or without `import numpy`).

Comment: Anyway, if your problem is any of the obvious ones, reinstalling is either not necessary (e.g., if you forgot to run the NumPy installer, just run it), or not sufficient (e.g., if you have two Python installations and keep mixing them up, reinstalling one of them isn't going to stop you from mixing it up with the other), so you probably need to find out the actual problem.

Comment: @talonmies: I think that's only a dup if the OP happens to be on Debian/Ubuntu/similar linux and installed everything via apt. We have no idea whether that's the case.

Comment: I have only one version of Python that I am aware of. I had to do a clean install of windows awhile ago so I know there is only one version on there.

Comment: @abarnert If anything by looking at the program I have so far. What would you recommend I install? My computer is 64 bit windows, and now I am not quite sure what links or what to get to make sure everything works.

Comment: Well, are you sure you installed NumPy? If you start up Python on the command line and `import numpy`, what happens?

Comment: Meanwhile, how did you install everything? If you want to start over, I'd suggesting using the latest python.org installer (for 2.7 or 3.4, whichever you want), and installing NumPy and friends via `pip` using the wheels from [Christoph Gohlke's repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Unlike a Windows installer package, a wheel install isn't likely to fail silently.

Comment: If it doesn't look like anything happens when you `import numpy`, that means it works. (You can test further with, say, `print(numpy.zeros((2,2)))`, if you really want to be sure.)

Comment: But if you want to start over from scratch, do what I said 3 comments up, installing all the same packages as before from Christoph Gohlke's wheels into a clean latest-version python.org Python. Just make sure that after erasing the old Python, you really don't have another old Python lying around.

Comment: @abarnert Using the wheel like this correct? "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.4.exe install D:\Users\user\Downloads\numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl"

Comment: @CharlesBoldescbkh2bankai: Looks right. (Assuming you went with 32-bit Python; otherwise you want the one that ends with `win_amd64.whl` or something like that.)